# Customizing Wordpress search form template (Genesis)

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis, search-form

I wanted to change my search form a bit by adding `autocomplete="off"` to the search input.

I initially looked for a simple filter like the following:

```
//* Customize search form input box text
add_filter( 'genesis_search_text', 'sp_search_text' );
function sp_search_text( $text ) {
    return esc_attr( 'Search my blog...' );
}
```

But because the `/genesis/lib/structure/search.php` did not have any variable like `autocomplete="%s"`, that attribute could not be targeted. I probably had to introduce it directly, so I copied the `search.php` from the parent theme folder to the child theme folder folder.

The original code of the file was the following:

```
<?php

/**
 * Replace the default search form with a Genesis-specific form.
 *
 * The exact output depends on whether the child theme supports HTML5 or not.
 *
 * Applies the `genesis_search_text`, `genesis_search_button_text`, `genesis_search_form_label` and
 * `genesis_search_form` filters.
 *
 * @since 0.2.0
 *
 * @return string HTML markup for search form.
 */

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'genesis_search_form' );

function genesis_search_form() {
    $search_text = get_search_query() ? apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query() ) : apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) . ' &#x02026;' );

    $button_text = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_button_text', esc_attr__( 'Search', 'genesis' ) );

    $onfocus = "if ('" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "' === this.value) {this.value = '';}";
    $onblur  = "if ('' === this.value) {this.value = '" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "';}";

    // Empty label, by default. Filterable.
    $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_form_label', '' );

    $value_or_placeholder = ( get_search_query() == '' ) ? 'placeholder' : 'value';

    if ( genesis_html5() ) {

        $form  = sprintf( '<form %s>', genesis_attr( 'search-form' ) );

        if ( genesis_a11y( 'search-form' ) ) {

            if ( '' == $label )  {
                $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) );
            }

            $form_id = uniqid( 'searchform-' );

            $form .= sprintf(
                '<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><label class="search-form-label screen-reader-text" for="%s">%s</label><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" id="%s" %s="%s" /><input type="submit" value="%s" /></form>',
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                esc_html( $label ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );

        } else {

            $form .= sprintf(
                '%s<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" %s="%s" /><input type="submit" value="%s"  /></form>',
                esc_html( $label ),
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );
        }


    } else {

        $form = sprintf(
            '<form method="get" class="searchform search-form" action="%s" role="search" >%s<input type="text" value="%s" name="s" class="s search-input" onfocus="%s" onblur="%s" /><input type="submit" class="searchsubmit search-submit" value="%s" /></form>',
            home_url( '/' ),
            esc_html( $label ),
            esc_attr( $search_text ),
            esc_attr( $onfocus ),
            esc_attr( $onblur ),
            esc_attr( $button_text )
        );

    }

    return apply_filters( 'genesis_search_form', $form, $search_text, $button_text, $label );

}
```

Then I removed the original filter and added my filter:

```
remove_filter( 'get_search_form', 'genesis_search_form' );

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );
```

And added `autocomplete="off"` to the search input, so the current is:

```
<?php

/**
 * Replace the default search form with a Genesis-specific form.
 *
 * The exact output depends on whether the child theme supports HTML5 or not.
 *
 * Applies the `genesis_search_text`, `genesis_search_button_text`, `genesis_search_form_label` and
 * `genesis_search_form` filters.
 *
 * @since 0.2.0
 *
 * @return string HTML markup for search form.
 */

remove_filter( 'get_search_form', 'genesis_search_form' );

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_search_form' );

function my_search_form() {
    $search_text = get_search_query() ? apply_filters( 'the_search_query', get_search_query() ) : apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) . ' &#x02026;' );

    $button_text = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_button_text', esc_attr__( 'Search', 'genesis' ) );

    $onfocus = "if ('" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "' === this.value) {this.value = '';}";
    $onblur  = "if ('' === this.value) {this.value = '" . esc_js( $search_text ) . "';}";

    // Empty label, by default. Filterable.
    $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_form_label', '' );

    $value_or_placeholder = ( get_search_query() == '' ) ? 'placeholder' : 'value';

    if ( genesis_html5() ) {

        $form  = sprintf( '<form %s>', genesis_attr( 'search-form' ) );

        if ( genesis_a11y( 'search-form' ) ) {

            if ( '' == $label )  {
                $label = apply_filters( 'genesis_search_text', __( 'Search this website', 'genesis' ) );
            }

            $form_id = uniqid( 'searchform-' );

            $form .= sprintf(
                '<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><label class="search-form-label screen-reader-text" for="%s">%s</label><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" id="%s" %s="%s" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto" /><input type="submit" value="%s" /></form>',
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                esc_html( $label ),
                esc_attr( $form_id ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );

        } else {

            $form .= sprintf(
                '%s<meta itemprop="target" content="%s"/><input itemprop="query-input" type="search" name="s" %s="%s" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto" /><input type="submit" value="%s"  /></form>',
                esc_html( $label ),
                home_url( '/?s={s}' ),
                $value_or_placeholder,
                esc_attr( $search_text ),
                esc_attr( $button_text )
            );
        }


    } else {

        $form = sprintf(
            '<form method="get" class="searchform search-form" action="%s" role="search" >%s<input type="text" value="%s" name="s" class="s search-input" onfocus="%s" onblur="%s" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" dir="auto" /><input type="submit" class="searchsubmit search-submit" value="%s" /></form>',
            home_url( '/' ),
            esc_html( $label ),
            esc_attr( $search_text ),
            esc_attr( $onfocus ),
            esc_attr( $onblur ),
            esc_attr( $button_text )
        );

    }

    return apply_filters( 'my_search_form', $form, $search_text, $button_text, $label );

}
```

It currently works perfectly on the homepage, but in any other page only the header and the tagline are generated. I could edit the parent theme files directly but wanted an alternative to avoid messing everything up. Any insight or suggestions?

---

[Documentation for get_search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/)

[Documentation for genesis_search_form](http://genesis.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/genesis_search_form/)

[Documentation for Genesis Snippets](http://my.studiopress.com/documentation/snippets)

Comment: Where is you `my_search_form()` function?

Comment: In the searchform.php I remove the original `genesis_search_form()` filter and replace all instances of `genesis_search_form()` with `my_search_form()` and add the `autocomplete="off"` to the code. The errors are error 500 where the entire or parts of the page appear white, it seems that the code can't run properly outside of its original location, but I wanted an alternative to avoid editing the parent theme framework directly.

Comment: What is the reson for removing the original... There should be no reason that it would affect your new form as long as you call your form instead of genesis.

Comment: Thought that there would be conflict. But having it there didn't help either way.

Comment: It currently works perfectly on the homepage, but in any other page only the header and the tagline are generated.

Comment: wouldn't a 2-3 lines javascript solution be the best choice here if this trouble is done only for the autocomplete feature?

Comment: Probably, I thought about that at first. If it was a permanent element I would have done it with jQuery, but then thought I that generating it with php and then add the extra elements with jQuery wouldn't be very efficient. So in the end, I opted for using only 1 language for its entire generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the `genesis_search_form` function applies `genesis_search_form` filter at the end. Instead of re-writing the whole `genesis_search_form` function, you can use that to manipulate the form and use `DOMDocument` inside a new filter to add the `autocomplete` attribute you want. Try the following code inside your child theme `functions.php` and see if it works:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', 'my_search_form_filter', 5 );
function my_search_form_filter($form) {

    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTML($form);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
    $input = $xpath->query('//input[@name="s"]');
    if ($input->length > 0) {
        $input->item(0)->setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
    }

    # remove <!DOCTYPE 
    $document->removeChild($document->doctype); 
    # remove <html><body></body></html> 
    $document->replaceChild($document->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $document->firstChild);
    $form_html = $document->saveHTML();

    return $form_html;
}
```

Don't forget to disable your code that disables the default `get_search_form` filter and adds yours.

**EDIT**

The previous code was wrong, please update with the latest above code that works. I have tested it with `genesis` and `genesis-child` themes.

Here you can find my [Dev Wordpress](http://wp.dev.lytrax.net/) site with the `genesis` theme installed and you can inspect the search input box and see it has the `autocomplete` attribute set to `off`: http://wp.dev.lytrax.net/

And here is a screenshot showing the form search input element having the `autocomplete` attribute:

[image: Wordpress screenshot]

**EDIT 2**

The `genesis-sample` theme, uses the HTML5 search form and it includes some `meta` tags inside the code that `createDocumentFragment` element can handle using `appendXML`, thus it throws many warnings and it fails to continue. You can't see those PHP warnings, because most likely you have them disabled. Please try my updated code. Add it to the end of the `genesis-sample/functions.php` file and check if it adds the `autocomplete` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your approach is interesting. But I think that something is not right because when I wright that code in the `functions.php` only the the `head` and an empty `body` without classes are generated in all the pages.

Comment: @SilverLink please see my updated answer and try the new code. Don't forget to disable all the filters and changes you have made to the search functions of the genesis theme.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I'm so sorry but I just can't reproduce your example, even after downloading fresh framework and genesis sample. Now it removes all the search forms, I will try to upload images to show you soon.

Comment: @SilverLink which version of genesis and PHP do you have? Can you please try to debug this by adding `return 'debug: <pre>'.htmlentities($form_html).'</pre>';` to the end of `my_search_form_filter` function and update with what you see instead of the search boxes?

Comment: PHP version:  5.6.29. The result was: "debug: "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137800/discussion-between-christos-lytras-and-silverlink).